# How to config the object detection pipeline config to train a SSD-mobilenet model using the SSD512 architecture instead of SSD300?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I want to train an pedestrian detection model using tensorflow object detection API.

The training set I use is a combination of the MSCOCO and the SPID.
And 10 percent of the SPID as the test set.

I choose the `ssd-mobilenet` model to train for its highest speed.

I have tried tuning several hyper-parameter, such as LR, LR-decay, SSD min and max scale, SSD aspect ratios.

The highest mAP@0.50 score I got is 0.68, which is not bad considering the difficulty of the SPID dataset.

When I was doing error analysis, I found that in most missing-detect cases, the model fails to detect relatively small objects (pedestrians).

After searching the internet, I found that one of the most common problems when deploying the SSD object detection is its lack of capability to detect small objects.

Many say using the SSD512 model may help. 
However, I can't find any docs say how to do it in `tensorflow` object detection docs.

I tried to change the

**image_resizer section** in the pipeline config direct from 300 to 512, but the training result performance worse than before, and I am pretty sure it's not the right way to do because the base architecture of SSD512 is not the same with SSD300.

Anyone know How to config the object detection pipeline config to train a `SSD-mobilenet` model using the SSD512 architecture instead of `SSD300`?